# What's this little green arrow on top of the "hamburger stack" in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I just noticed that there was a little greenish colored arrow on top of Chrome's "hamburger stack". Does anyone know what it means?

[image: ss of arrow]

Comment: Unless you have the hobby of reading the Chrome help page, you couldn't come with an answer of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it means you have a update to Chrome that's ready to be used if you relaunch. Under the "hamburger stack" if you go to "About Google Chrome":

[image: ss of update]

#### EDIT #1

Thanks to [@Braiam](https://superuser.com/users/235569/braiam) for finding this extra bit of info. Apparently there are 3 colors that vary from green to yellow to red, depending on how long the update's been available, but hasn't been installed yet.

- [Google Chrome: Why are the Google Chrome update arrows different colors?](http://www.quora.com/Google-Chrome/Why-are-the-Google-Chrome-update-arrows-different-colors)

That thread also referenced [this bit of code from the Chromium project](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/upgrade_detector_impl.cc?revision=204942) that discusses the elevation of the arrow color.

> Aaron Boodman, Technical Lead - Chrome, Chrome Extensions
>   Votes by Anthony Yeh, Anonymous, Shrey Banga, Max Morozenko, and 6 more.
>   It gets more and more urgent (green, yellow, red) the longer you go without restarting.